PowerShell script to move the files to one folder to another in same SharePoint Online library
Good day. I have 5K+ files in "00" folder and each file having a Document date (single line of text). I need to move the files from "00" folder to January, February and March folder based on Document date. I need to write the PowerShell script. Any idea on this.


You probably want to have a look at Move-PnPFile

Hi @Daniel
,
Thanks for your reply. I am using "Move-PnPFile" to move the file. But as I mentioned in my thread, I need to check each file documentdate and based on that I need to move. can you assist me with this?
